# Centrality measures and interpretation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova, t-test, graph-theory

I am new to graph theory and I have some questioning.

First of all, how can I determine the significant of two different degree centrality means and two different closeness centrality means? For example, I have a network of international organizations which are public or private, but I don't know how to determine if the difference between their means is significant or not :

```
     Type          x
```

1 private 0.05613594
2  public 0.05668078

```
     Type        x
```

1 private 4.441558
2  public 8.750000

In order to evaluate if the type of international organization is linked with a higher degree centrality (and with a higher closeness centrality), I performed an ANOVA test; However, does it the right test to determined a possible link ?

Thanks you very much

Comment: these questions have nothing to do with graph theory, they're just basic hypothesis testing questions.

Comment: @Antoine not true. Statistics in a graph context require different techniques, because nodes are not independent.

Comment: Yes, you are right Antoine but one part of my question is related to graph theory and considering the difference between the result of centrality score. I'm not familiar with graph theory and even if  a difference of 0.01 appeared not large, maybe in graph theory this the case between two closeness centrality degree results.

Comment: @ssdecontrol violation of the independence assumptions is not specific to graphs

Comment: @Antoine no, but there are graph-specific ways to handle those violations. I'm not an expert in them but I know there are techniques like the quadratic assignment procedure that are designed specifically for adjacency matrices.

Comment: @ssdecontrol The problem of dependence is (usually) ignored in the field of networks. For example, when looking at degree distributions which is similar to the power law, I've never heard of scientist discussing the independence assumption before, although what you say seems very sensible.

Comment: @tintinthong interesting. My only substantive exposure to networks is through a "social network analysis" course, where the instructor (a sociologist) made a big point out of the non-independence of graph data.